# No class Def found error while running jar file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a java code in jmeter by jar file.The jmeter test  running properly but it throws error when the method inside the jar file is called.The jar file is properly running when running from CMD and jenkins.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
    at CloudBLM_API.ApiAuthentication.<init>(ApiAuthentication.java:23) ~[ModelPublishWebGL.jar:?]
    at CloudBLM_API.Publisher.<init>(Publisher.java:18) ~[ModelPublishWebGL.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:250) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at Script6.run(Script6.groovy:13) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:931) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:569) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells that there is no [json-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple) jar in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) so you need to:

1. Download [json-simple-1.1.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar) and drop it to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. The error should go away. If you experience similar problems repeat it for every dependency .jar used in your Groovy script
4. According to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.4.1 (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
5. It's hard to recommend something without seeing your full code, just in case be informed that there is built-in JSON support in Groovy so if you're parsing JSON using external libraries the logic can be replaced with Groovy specific functions, see [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) Groovy documentation chapter for more details

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.I tried adding jars manually and i am using the updated version of Jmeter(5.4.1).But now the sampler(http request) in which i call the jar is not getting executed.